TASK [Add apt repository for Kubernetes] FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to update apt cache:

I am trying to provision a Kubernetes cluster using Ansible. My playbook includes tasks to install Docker and Kubernetes, configure the cluster, and set up networking. However, I am encountering an error related to the use of local_action:
ERROR! 'local_action' is not a valid attribute for a Play

Here is a snippet of the playbook where the error occurs:
- name: Copy join command to local file
  local_action: copy content="{{ join_command.stdout_lines[0] }}" dest="./join-command"

I have read that local_action is deprecated and should be replaced with delegate_to: localhost. However, I'm not sure how to modify my playbook to use delegate_to instead.
Could someone please help me understand how to rewrite this task using delegate_to: localhost or suggest an alternative approach?
Thank you!


local action still working on ansible [core 2.15.3].  But I to have started using delegate_to. Just run the copy module like you would normally do and put delegate_to at the same indentation as copy.

All in the delegation documentation
